# in jq, can a select be optional (i.e. if nothing found - don't filter out the element)

Tags: json, shell, command-line, jq

I'm using JQ to filter a list of things, and then for each found thing - reformat it to a single string by extracting values from sub-keys.

The problem is that is one of the sub-keys is missing, the entire line is omitted.

Consider the following example document:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "A",
      "active": true,
      "tags": [
        { "name": "foo", "value": 1 }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "B",
      "active": true,
      "tags": [
        { "name": "foo", "value":1 },
        {"name": "bar", "value":2}
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "C",
      "active": false,
      "tags": [
        { "name": "foo", "value":1 },
        { "name": "baz", "value":3 }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I want to select all active items, and create for each a single line describing the item's ID as well as the value of both its `foo` and `bar` tags.

Initially I've done something like this:

```
jq -r '
   .items[] | 
   select ( .active == true ) | 
   ( .id + " -> [" + 
     ( .tags[] | select( .name == "foo" ) | .value | tostring ) +
     ", " +
     ( .tags[] | select( .name == "bar" ) | .value | tostring ) +
     "]"
   )
'
```

But because `bar` is only included in item `B`, the line for item `A` gets filtered out.

Is there a way to make the sub-select optional so that if the select fails, I get an empty string or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could patch your query using `if ... then ... else ... end` or perhaps `//`, but it would be better to address some other issues as well, e.g. as follows:

```
 .items[]
 | select ( .active == true ) 
 | .id + " -> ["
   + (.tags | map(select(.name == "foo") | .value) | join(";"))
   + ", "
   + (.tags | map(select(.name == "bar") | .value) | join(";"))
   + "]"
```

With jq version 1.5 or earlier, you would need to add a call to `tostring`, or to use string interpolation, e.g.

```
   .items[]
   | select ( .active == true ) 
   | .id 
     + " -> [\(.tags | map(select(.name == "foo") | "\(.value)") | join(";") ), "
     +      "\(.tags | map(select(.name == "bar") | "\(.value)" ) | join(";"))"
     + "]"
```

### Variant using `first` and string interpolation

```
.items[]
| select ( .active == true )
| (first(.tags[] | select(.name == "foo") | .value) // "")  as $v
| (first(.tags[] | select(.name == "bar") | .value) // "")  as $w
| "\(.id) -> [\($v), \($w)]"
```

Using string interpolation circumvents the potential need to use `tostring`.

Comment: I understand you use `map` and `join` because you assume there are multiple tags with the same name. This is not the case: the model represented by the sample input forbids that. Can you show how `if...then...else...end` would be used (I already figured out `//`)?

Comment: `if .name == "foo" then whatever else . end` only pipes content through `whatever` if `name` is `foo`, and otherwise leaves it unmodified, which is exactly what you're asking how to do.

Comment: @Guss - I did not exactly "assume there are multiple tags" - I wanted to show how all possible multiplicities (which includes 0) could be handled.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood what `map()` does, thanks for clarifying. Unfortunately, `map()` + `join()` generate an output surrounded by brackets, so `A` generates `[]` for the `bar` tag and `B` generates `[2]` for the `bar` tag. I have no need for this additional output.

Comment: `if...then...else...end` also doesn't work for me - for some reason if I use `( .tags[] | if .name == "foo" then .value else "" end | tostring )` (and `.name == "bar"` for the second part), then running the sample input generates: `A -> [1, ]\n
B -> [1, ]\n
B -> [, ]\n
B -> [1, 2]\n
B -> [, 2]\n
` which is definetly not what I need - and I don't understand why `B` is duplicated 4 times.

Comment: @Guss, have you worked with XQuery? The way sequences work in jq is quite similar -- if you pass a sequence (not a list, which is one object, but a comma-separated sequence, which is several objects) into a function, you get a sequence of outputs from that function, akin to it being run once per input; hence the duplication.

Comment: @peak, ...btw, I'm actually having some trouble deploying your answer; with jq 1.5, it yields an error `jq: error (at <stdin>:27): string ("") and number (1) cannot be added`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - that's what the `tostring` is for in the OP.

Comment: @Guss, obviously, yes.

Comment: Also, regarding my complaint about `map()` before - I didn't put in the `join()` in my test, hence the additional brackets from array seralization.

Comment: I eventually used the "alternative" syntax as demonstrated in the third example, but without string interpolation or using `first`, so its just `(( .tags[] | select( .name == "foo" ) | .value | tostring ) // "")`